# How do you get a country's GDP per capita in Euros?

Tags: curated-data, units, finance

Right now, I'm getting the data in U.S. Dollars and converting it to Euros like this:

```
CountryData[
  "Mexico", {"GDPPerCapita", All}] /. {x_, y_} -> {x, 
   UnitConvert[Quantity[y, "USDollars"], "Euros"]}
```

Is there a way to shorten this code or to directly get the data in Euros? If there's a way for both, please post each of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
euro = FinancialData["USD/EUR"]
```

> 0.8139

```
DateListPlot[
 TimeSeriesMap[#*euro &, CountryData["Mexico", {"GDPPerCapita", All}]],
 GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Inspect the values with

```
TimeSeriesMap[#*euro &, CountryData["Mexico", {"GDPPerCapita", All}]]["Values"] // QuantityMagnitude
```

Comment: However, this gives the GDP/capita as measured in contemporary USD, converted into today's EUR. Ideally one should use the historical exchange rates in order to get a more accurate picture.

Comment: @OleksandrR. True, but there isn't a 1970 exchange rate. As you certainly know the euro was introduced much later.

Comment: Well, in case one needs GDP per capita in EUR going back further than 1999 (which may make the question somewhat ill-defined), the exchange rates for the preceding ECU and EUA could be used instead. Alternatively, and probably more meaningfully, the figures can be CPI-normalized and presented in real current EUR.